# Function works when passing a string, but when trying to pass multiple strings stored in a list, it does not work

Tags: python, string, list, function

I have the below code that is working, defining a list containing one string, and the function. This works correctly and returns the data that I need

```py
a = ["REQ-ETH"]

def klines_func(a):
    for i in a:
        klines = client.get_kline_data(a, '5min', 1507479171, 1510278278)
    return klines
```

However, when changing a to `["REQ-ETH","REQ-BTC"]`, the code does not work (resulting in an API exception error, however when trying the `"REQ-BTC"` pair alone, the code works as well).

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KucoinAPIException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-2cf04cd53d1c> in <module>
----> 1 klines_func(a)

<ipython-input-26-45a04a1bad02> in klines_func(a)
      1 def klines_func(a):
      2     for i in a:
----> 3         klines = client.get_kline_data(a, '5min', 1507479171, 1510278278)
      4     return klines

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kucoin/client.py in get_kline_data(self, symbol, kline_type, start, end)
   1833             data['endAt'] = int(time.time())
   1834 
-> 1835         return self._get('market/candles', False, data=data)
   1836 
   1837     # Websocket Endpoints

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kucoin/client.py in _get(self, path, signed, **kwargs)
    185 
    186     def _get(self, path, signed=False, **kwargs):
--> 187         return self._request('get', path, signed, **kwargs)
    188 
    189     def _post(self, path, signed=False, **kwargs):

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kucoin/client.py in _request(self, method, path, signed, **kwargs)
    156 
    157         response = getattr(self.session, method)(uri, **kwargs)
--> 158         return self._handle_response(response)
    159 
    160     @staticmethod

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kucoin/client.py in _handle_response(response)
    171 
    172             if 'code' in res and res['code'] != "200000":
--> 173                 raise KucoinAPIException(response)
    174 
    175             if 'success' in res and not res['success']:

KucoinAPIException: KucoinAPIException 400100: This pair is not provided at present.
```

Essentially, this works for one string but when trying to iterate with a for loop and multiple strings it does not work. I am very new to Python but appreciate any support!

Comment: " the code does not work (resulting in an API exception error" this is not an adequate descrption of the problem. [Show us exactly what goes wrong](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/).

Comment: https://python-kucoin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kucoin.html#kucoin.client.Client.get_kline_data says it accepts a string as the argument

Comment: hi Karl, i have copied in the error. "This pair is not provided at present". However, the data IS available when queried separately, (when the code for a changes to a = ["REQ-BTC"] , the query works fine). It seems to just throw an error when a list is passed into the argument. The API documentation requires a string for that argument, but i would like to pass multiple strings at once and not sure what the best way to do it is; so i went with a list

Comment: Would it be more correct to use `i` instead of `a` in `client.get_kline_data(a, '5min', 1507479171, 1510278278)`? I'm guessing you will need to call the function once with each string (`i`, not `a`), then append the results into a list and return that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `client.get_kline_data` is expecting a *single* string, then you want to call this function with the parameter `i` instead of `a` in your loop.

In your current loop, you are not using `i`, but `a`, so you essentially try to call several time the API function with the whole list.